# Dereferencing pointers confusion

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn about pointers in the C language. But I have a question regarding dereferencing them.

This piece of code works fine, it displays 'i' as I desire.

#### Code-1

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunction(char** str);

int main()
{
    char *name = "Gianni"; 
    myfuntion(&name); 
    return 0;
}

void myfunction(char** str){

    char* test = *str;
    printf("%c", test[1]);
}
```

But what I guessed to have the same result turns out to be a little bit different. My question is why do I not get the same result from the second piece of code?

I dereferenced the pointer so it points to the first character again and can read it until the '\0' terminator. So I thought it would be possible to display the single characters here as well.

#### Code-2

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunction(char** str);

int main()
{
    char *name = "Gianni"; 
    myfuntion(&name); 
    return 0;
}

void myfunction(char** str){
    printf("%c", *str[1]);
}
```

Comment: Try to stay away from questions of the form "why doesn't code piece A do the same as code piece B?", instead go for "why doesn't code piece A do what I want which is X, which code piece B does". The reason is that people will first have to figure out what B does, and then have to figure out, and sometimes guess, if what B does is what you *actually* wanted to do.

Comment: Well I have reference the code..so now if you edit -- it will be difiicult for me.

Comment: @coderredoc ofcourse, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [**precedence**](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) issue.(Array subscript `[]` has higher precedence than dereference `*`). You should try

```
(*str)[1]
```

This will give you the correct result. In earlier case (In Code-2) you had [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You were de-referencing `str[1]` which is pointing to out of bound memory.

So initially what you were doing in Code-2

```
*str[1] --> *(*(str+1))
```

Now what we did,

```
(*str)[1] --> *((*str)+1)
```

Well in the modification you are basically getting the address of the array (string literals are array which decayed into pointer) and then you index into correct position - which will give you the correct result.

---

Well if you check earlier example you will see the similarity. Earlier code  (Code-1) you print `temp[1]` which is `*(temp+1)` But what is `temp`? In the line before you did this `temp = *str` so what is it you are  doing?

```
*(temp+1) --> *(*str+1) --> *((*str)+1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. This does indeed solve my problem. I will take a beter look at precedence in C.

Comment: What I was doing was actually a test if that would work or not to be honest. So I created a new char pointer.